# Android toolbar change title practices for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering if there is some common pattern of best practice for updating toolbar title when navigating fragments.

I used one approach which is kinda ok, as it let fragments to restore their title when resuming application which is really important.

I used to create an interface with setToolbarTitle method.

```
public interface InteractionListener {
    void setToolbarTitle(@StringRes int title);
}
```

Then I would implement it in root activity.

```
@Override
public void setToolbarTitle(@StringRes int title) {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

And on fragment onStart callback I would set the title:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    listener.setToolbarTitle(title);
}
```

But as you this approach requires 3 different parts. I was wondering, maybe there is a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in Fragment's `onResume` method. Consider, that you can navigate back the `FragmentManager` history and the title should then change accordingly, too.

Comment: In the end I chose this approach, as it makes fragments decoupled from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following seems fine to me. 
However, alternative you can use Activities with no Actionbar and manually add toolbar like this

extend your theme like this

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Apply theme like this in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyAwesomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    />
```

Then your activity and each fragment you can have its own toolbar like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Now Activity and each fragment can set its own title, and no need to update title on different lifecycle methods.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause each fragment to render it's own toolbar even though only single item value (title) differs for each fragment. It might be a premature optimisation but I think this is and overhead at least for this specific problem.

Comment: yeah you will need that, it will just take away the pain of setting title based on lifecycle methods